# Trying to get PHP program to get data from Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am very new to PHP and I am trying to write a simple program based on this tutorial, https://benmarshall.me/facebook-php-sdk/, to get my profile name off of Facebook.  But I keep getting an error. the problem appears to be with my path to autoload.php but I think I have the right path.  But maybe not.

Practice.php

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . 'Facebook/vendor/autoload.php'; // change path as needed

$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{}',
  'app_secret' => '{}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v3.3',
  //'default_access_token' => '{access-token}', // optional
]);

// Use one of the helper classes to get a Facebook\Authentication\AccessToken entity.
//   $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
//   $helper = $fb->getJavaScriptHelper();
//   $helper = $fb->getCanvasHelper();
//   $helper = $fb->getPageTabHelper();

try {
  // Get the \Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphUser object for the current user.
  // If you provided a 'default_access_token', the '{access-token}' is optional.
  $response = $fb->get('/me', '{access-token}');
} catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$me = $response->getGraphUser();
echo 'Logged in as ' . $me->getName();
```

Error Message

```
[north@oreo ~/Facebook]$ php Practice.php

Warning: require_once(/usr/home/north/FacebookFacebook/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/home/north/Facebook/Practice.php on line 2

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/usr/home/north/FacebookFacebook/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/share/pear') in /usr/home/north/Facebook/Practice.php on line 2
[north@oreo ~/Facebook]$
```

Comment: Well did you check that `autoload.php` exists in that folder???

Comment: I would expect it to be more like `vendor/facebook/autoload.php` but that assumes you have followed convension

Comment: ALso you appear to somehow have duplicated `Facebook` in `FacebookFacebook/vendor/autoload.php` So one assumes you are in the `Facebook` folder already

Comment: So maybe try `require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: @RiggsFolly that fixed that error but now I got another error.  I will try to figure it out if not then I will post another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comments said all I needed to do to fix it was change `Facebook/vendor/autoload.php`  to  `/vendor/autoload.php`